# Eurostar and "Attestation de déplacement et de voyage"

Tags: covid-19, eurostar

With new travel restrictions that French authorities imposed starting from the 31 January 2021, how vigilant are the border checks for "Attestation de déplacement et de voyage", when boarding Eurostar for London in Lille or Paris? Do they deny many passengers from boarding because they find the reason / supporting documentation not sufficient?

Comment: I hadn't heard of this particular restriction (the prime minister emphasized restrictions on entry, not exit, in his last press conference). For reference, it's [detailed here](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage#from5)

Comment: Speculating a bit but thinking about it, I suspect they would. The real question is whether they check the supporting evidence very carefully. But once it's not possible to ignore that the reason is flimsy, I am pretty sure that either border guards or Eurostar staff would find themselves compelled to act on it.

Comment: Do you have a valid reason to travel? If you do and have the proper paperwork and test then it shouldn’t be a problem. If you don’t, stay at home.

Comment: @jcaron *and the proper paperwork* is key, it's easy to imagine how you could have a valid reason but fail to have the right paperwork. There is also a bit of arbitrariness in the specific set of reasons and paperwork accepted by each country. It's perfectly possible to have a serious reason to travel while still being worried about the checks. We don't even know whether France is home for the OP.